# Inconsistent Rules in Anime/Manga Universes

Tags: discussion

Most anime/manga focuses on the story and characters, based on the backdrop of the Universe the story is set in. Fantasy worlds usually come with special rules (the "Physics" of the world) that deviate from the reader's reality (e.g. rules of the Death Note, rules of the Holy Grail War in Fate/Zero, law of "Equivalent Exchange" in Fullmetal Alchemist). Should we encourage questions on the implications and contradictions between the rules?

While the rules may appear consistent enough for the reader to accept the fantasy world and focus on the story, it is natural for readers to peer beyond the surface and question the implications of the rules. However, beyond the surface, the rules often contradict each other and do not form a consistent framework, exemplified by the famous plot-holes in time-travel anime/manga. I think it is pointless to enquire deeper into plot-holes, because probably even the writer of the story doesn't have an answer other than "please focus on the story and appreciate it".

In short, I think questions about rules of the Universe that affect plot events should be encouraged, but not questions about why certain rules contradict and form plot-holes.

Comment: Somewhat relevant: When answering these questions, I think it's really important for users to cite their information. Since we're talking about fictional worlds with magic/alchemy/whatever, it's harder to tell the difference between an answer based off of a certain scene and an answer based off of whatever the user thinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discussions about the universe...can lead one astray pretty quickly.

Let's consider, for example, the partially defined universe of *Last Exile*.

- What led Prester to being an hourglass, and why did the two nations' climates differ so much?
- How did the Grand Stream come to be?
- What happened to Prester after the mass exodus?
- *Where* was Prester?
- What is Claudia?

Many of these questions can be answered (thankfully!) with some side material from the box set, but others are pretty abstract and kind of out there.  Now, there are some good questions that can come out of this, but we would have to be careful that the questions focused more on the concrete plot, and not the abstract thought.